# Internet connection problems after running VS instances for a long time

Tags: windows-10, internet-connection, visual-studio

I'm working on a .Net project for which I have to run multiple instances of Visual Studio. Everything works just fine, but I noticed that after a few hours of having these instances running on my machine my internet starts acting up. Suddenly I can't access a lot of websites via any browser, my other apps on my windows can't access the internet anymore. The only way to fix this is either by restarting my machine or closing all my VS instances. How can I fix this please?

Comment: I regularly have multiple Visual Studio instances open for weeks at a time on Windows 10 and do not have this issue. Can you give more details? What version of Visual Studio are you running? Does the problem happen if you just have one instance of Visual Studio open? Is this happening if you don't have any of your code running? Do you have any Visual Studio extensions running?

Comment: Same for me, it's been years for always running multiple instances and never had this problem until now. I'm currently running 8 VS instances, that's 8 APIs and it takes quite a long time before giving me this problem so it's not really that easy to reproduce. I don't have any extensions other than the default ones. And yes, it happens when I'm running my code.

Comment: Update drivers and check for updates to VS?

Comment: My VS is update to date and so are my drivers.

Comment: So apparently my drivers weren't really up to date even though that's what windows was telling me, CCleaner updated my wifi drivers and I'm no longer having this problem.